Missing symbols when statically linking library with static dependencies
I have an executable (test) using a static library (A), which uses another static library (B). The file structure is as follow:
test: {
  CMakeLists.txt,
  main.cpp,
  deps: {
    A: {
      CMakeLists.txt,
      include: {
        A.h
      },
      src: {
        A.cpp
      },
      deps: {
        B: {
          CMakeLists.txt,
          include: {
            B.h
          },
          src: {
            B.cpp
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

The files look like:
main.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include <A.h>
int main() {
std::cout << "hello: " << A::get() << std::endl;
}

A.h:
namespace A {
int get();
}

A.cpp:
#include "A.h"
#include <B.h>
int A::get() {
return B::get();
}

B.h:
namespace B {
int get();
}

B.cpp:
#include "B.h"
int B::get() {
return 7;
}

CMakeLists.txt (test):
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(test LANGUAGES CXX)
include(ExternalProject)
add_executable(test main.cpp)
ExternalProject_Add(project_A
PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/deps/A"
SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/A"
CMAKE_ARGS
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/deps/A
-DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=ON
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
)
add_dependencies(test project_A)
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/deps/A/lib/libA.a")
target_include_directories(test PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/deps/A/include")

CMakeLists.txt (A):
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(A LANGUAGES CXX)
include(ExternalProject)
add_library(A STATIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/A.cpp")
target_include_directories(A PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
ExternalProject_Add(project_B
PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/deps/B"
SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/B"
CMAKE_ARGS
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/deps/B
-DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=ON
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
)
target_link_libraries(A PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/deps/B/lib/libB.a")
target_include_directories(A PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/deps/B/include")
add_dependencies(A project_B)
install(TARGETS A)
install(DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include" DESTINATION .)

CMakeLists.txt (B):
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(B LANGUAGES CXX)
include(ExternalProject)
add_library(B STATIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/B.cpp")
target_include_directories(B PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
install(TARGETS B)
install(DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include" DESTINATION .)

**Why are B's symbols when building (see error below)? How can I do this without explicitly linking test to B, I want to encapsulate that logic in A. So, that any executable that wants to use A doesn't need to know every dependency that A might need.
Note: These dependencies are right now in subdirectories only for sake of simplicity, so I'd like to avoid using add_subdirectory:**
At test root:
cmake -S. -Bbuild
...
cmake --build build
[ 10%] Creating directories for 'project_A'
[ 20%] No download step for 'project_A'
[ 30%] No update step for 'project_A'
[ 40%] No patch step for 'project_A'
[ 50%] Performing configure step for 'project_A'
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 15.0.0.15000309
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done (0.3s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /Documents/test/build/deps/A/src/project_A-build
[ 60%] Performing build step for 'project_A'
[ 10%] Creating directories for 'project_B'
[ 20%] No download step for 'project_B'
[ 30%] No update step for 'project_B'
[ 40%] No patch step for 'project_B'
[ 50%] Performing configure step for 'project_B'
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 15.0.0.15000309
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done (0.2s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /Documents/test/deps/A/build/deps/B/src/project_B-build
[ 60%] Performing build step for 'project_B'
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/B.dir/src/B.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX static library libB.a
[100%] Built target B
[ 70%] Performing install step for 'project_B'
[100%] Built target B
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /Documents/test/deps/A/build/deps/B/lib/libB.a
-- Installing: /Documents/test/deps/A/build/deps/B/./include
-- Installing: /Documents/test/deps/A/build/deps/B/./include/B.h
[ 80%] Completed 'project_B'
[ 80%] Built target project_B
[ 90%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/A.dir/src/A.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX static library libA.a
[100%] Built target A
[ 70%] Performing install step for 'project_A'
[ 80%] Built target project_B
[100%] Built target A
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /Documents/test/build/deps/A/lib/libA.a
-- Installing: /Documents/test/build/deps/A/./include
-- Installing: /Documents/test/build/deps/A/./include/A.h
[ 80%] Completed 'project_A'
[ 80%] Built target project_A
[ 90%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable test

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"B::get()", referenced from:
A::get() in libA.a[2](A.cpp.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

If my approach is entirely wrong or an anti-pattern please let me know the best practices for this.

The file libA.a doesn't encapsulate any information about linking with libB.a. This is just how static libraries work. For a static library linkage information could be stored only in a CMake target. But when use ExternalProject_Add you have no access to CMake targets of the external project. (Your code highlights that constraint when links with the library A by its full path). For access a subproject's targets, you need to use add_subdirectory approach or its improved version - FetchContent.


How can I do this without explicitly linking test to B, I want to encapsulate that logic in A.
So, that any executable that wants to use A doesn't need to know every dependency that A
might need.
Is my approach is entirely wrong or an anti-pattern please let me know the best
practices for this.
[Edit post]

It's your intention that libA should provide its client test with
complete abstraction from libA's dependency libB. Not only
should test need only to #include the header(s) of libA, not libB's, but
libA should provide automatic transitivity of its linkage dependencies, i.e.

the linkage of test depends on libA
the linkage of libA depends on libB
therefore the linkage of test depends on libB

but for the linkage of test it will be sufficient to input libA, and libA
itself will inform the static linker of its dependency on libB.
Not with static libraries.
This is doable with shared (dynamic) libraries. With static libraries it's not - it doesn't make sense.
Reading the static-libraries tag wiki will help.
A static library:

Cannot not be produced by the static linker; is produced the by the archiver, ar.
Is not a linkable file.
Is a bag (archive) of un-linked but statically linkable files (object files).
Contains no information about its linkage dependencies (because
the object files contain no such information, and no linkage has been done to them
that could have discovered such information).
Contributes 1 or more of the bagged object files to a linkage target that depends on it,
into which they statically linked (physically merged) as if the library did not exist.
By default contributes nothing to a target that does not actually depend on it.

A shared library on the other hand:

Is be produced by the static linker.
Is a linkable file.
Is not a container of files.
Is an unitary binary file only different in detail from a program.
Contains information about its linkage dependencies (which the static linker
discovered and put there).
No part of it is physically merged into a linkage target. What it
contributes to a linkage target that depends on it is:

A note saying that the target depends on it.
Optionally, a note naming a directory where it might be found.
A number undefined dynamic symbol table entries for those symbols
that are resolved by the library.


By default it contributes nothing to a target that does not actually depend on it.

Since the static linker cannot produce a static library at all, it is also impossible
for the static linker to link a static library in the production of another static
library.
So when CMake reports the like of:
Linking CXX static library libA.a

it's kidding, as you'll see if you turn on VERBOSE. What it's actually doing is:
[100%] Linking CXX static library libB.a
/usr/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/B.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/B.dir/link.txt --verbose=1  #2
/usr/bin/ar qc libB.a CMakeFiles/B.dir/src/B.cpp.o      #3 `ar`
/usr/bin/ranlib libB.a      #4 `ranlib`

where

lines #3 and #4 are the commands in the "link script" CMakeFiles/A.dir/link.txt at
line #2.
line #3: ar puts the object file CMakeFiles/A.dir/src/A.cpp.o in the bag libA.a
line #4: ranlib puts an extra file in the bag that is a symbol-to-object-file index table
for the convenience of the linker when it's looking in the bag for object files it wants.

I'm building on Linux and you're building on macOS, but you'll see very much the same thing.
The only way in which you can make test depend directly on libA.a and not also depend
directly on libB.a is by putting all the object files you put in bag B also into bag A. You can
"encapsulate the logic" of libB in libA only by making libA from the same object
files as libB, plus its own. Then you link test with libA. All the object files that
test needs are extracted and statically linked. The linkage of test has no dependency on
libB because libA has no dependency on libB. As far as test and libA are concerned,
libB might as well not exist.
You can get CMake to do that, of course, but it's not what you're trying to do.
How your linkage fails
Look again at that line:
/usr/bin/ar qc libA.a CMakeFiles/A.dir/src/A.cpp.o      #3 `ar`

where libA.a is being (kiddingly) "linked". The files that ar puts in the bag
are just A.cpp.o. There's no B.cpp.o; no mention of libB.a. So from this
point it's inevitable that:
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"B::get()", referenced from:
A::get() in libA.a[2](A.cpp.o)

will happen in the linkage of test. This is what the "linkage" of libA.a
amounts to despite the fact that you said, in A/CMakeLists.txt:
target_link_libraries(A PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/deps/B/lib/libB.a")

CMake ignores the intent of that because it knows there's actually no such thing as linking
one static library to produce another, and faking it is supposed to be done a different way.1
Yes, with shared libraries
Here is the technical synopsis.
The static linker produces programs and shared libraries. In both cases everything
that has been statically linked into the target is no longer a transitive dependency
for any further linkage, either for the static linker or the runtime linker.
The only residual dependencies of the target are dynamic dependencies, which
are shared libraries - the ones that the dynamic linker requires at runtime to
resolve the remaining undefined symbols in the target.
In both cases the static linker writes dependency information into the target in the
form of notes for the dynamic linker. The notes tell the dynamic linker the names
of the shared libraries that the static linker has found the target to depend on, and
optionally the names of non-default search directories where it can look for them.
With shared libraries libA and libB, the program test will contain the
information that it needs libA, and libA will contain the information
that it needs libB. Therefore test will need both of them at runtime. This is
only way in which linking libA  for target test can inform the static linker of
libAs dependency on libB.
The static linker not only writes the dynamic dependency notes in the program
or shared library that it outputs, it also reads and uses the dynamic linkage
notes in any shared libraries that are input to the linkage. This makes it possible
to link libA with libB in such a way (containing the right dynamic dependency notes)
that when it is turn is linked with test, libA itself will inform the static
linker of its dependency on libB and you will not need to do so yourself.
Slightly changed CMake files that work.
I've reproduced your build tree here on Ubuntu.
$ tree
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── deps
│   └── A
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── deps
│       │   └── B
│       │       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       │       ├── include
│       │       │   └── B.h
│       │       └── src
│       │           └── B.cpp
│       ├── include
│       │   └── A.h
│       └── src
│           └── A.cpp
└── main.cpp

It's not just a matter of changing STATIC to SHARED, but there's not much more
than that.
I've annotated the amendments to the three CMakeLists.txt files.
$ cat CMakeLists.txt 
## Test
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(test LANGUAGES CXX)
include(ExternalProject)
add_executable(test main.cpp)
ExternalProject_Add(project_A
PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/deps/A"
SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/A"
CMAKE_ARGS
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/deps/A
-DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=ON
# Old: -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON # New
)
add_dependencies(test project_A)
# Old: target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/deps/A/lib/libA.a")
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE A) # New
target_include_directories(test PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/deps/A/include")
target_link_directories(test PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/deps/A/lib") # New


$ cat deps/A/CMakeLists.txt
## A
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(A LANGUAGES CXX)
include(ExternalProject)
# Old: add_library(A STATIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/A.cpp")
# New: set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 1) Do this for macOS 
add_library(A SHARED "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/A.cpp") # New
set_target_properties(A PROPERTIES 
                        INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/deps/B/lib"
                        )
target_include_directories(A PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include") #New
ExternalProject_Add(project_B
PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/deps/B"
SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/B"
CMAKE_ARGS
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/deps/B
-DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=ON
# Old: -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON # New
)
# Old: target_link_libraries(A PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/deps/B/lib/libB.a")
target_link_libraries(A PRIVATE B) # New
target_include_directories(A PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/deps/B/include")
target_link_directories(A PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/deps/B/lib") # New 
add_dependencies(A project_B)
install(TARGETS A)
install(DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include" DESTINATION .)

$ cat deps/A/deps/B/CMakeLists.txt 
## B
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(B LANGUAGES CXX)
include(ExternalProject)
#Old add_library(B STATIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/B.cpp")
add_library(B SHARED "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/B.cpp") # New
target_include_directories(B PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
install(TARGETS B)
install(DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include" DESTINATION .)

Here's the build system generation:
$ cmake -S. -Bbuild
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done (0.3s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/imk/develop/so/cmake_prob/build

Here's the build:
$ cmake --build build
[ 10%] Creating directories for 'project_A'
[ 20%] No download step for 'project_A'
[ 30%] No update step for 'project_A'
[ 40%] No patch step for 'project_A'
[ 50%] Performing configure step for 'project_A'
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done (0.1s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/imk/develop/so/cmake_prob/build/deps/A/src/project_A-build
[ 60%] Performing build step for 'project_A'
[ 10%] Creating directories for 'project_B'
[ 20%] No download step for 'project_B'
[ 30%] No update step for 'project_B'
[ 40%] No patch step for 'project_B'
[ 50%] Performing configure step for 'project_B'
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done (0.1s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/imk/develop/so/cmake_prob/deps/A/build/deps/B/src/project_B-build
[ 60%] Performing build step for 'project_B'
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/B.dir/src/B.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared library libB.so
[100%] Built target B
[ 70%] Performing install step for 'project_B'
[100%] Built target B
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /home/imk/develop/so/cmake_prob/deps/A/build/deps/B/lib/libB.so
-- Installing: /home/imk/develop/so/cmake_prob/deps/A/build/deps/B/./include
-- Installing: /home/imk/develop/so/cmake_prob/deps/A/build/deps/B/./include/B.h
[ 80%] Completed 'project_B'
[ 80%] Built target project_B
[ 90%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/A.dir/src/A.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared library libA.so
[100%] Built target A
[ 70%] Performing install step for 'project_A'
[ 80%] Built target project_B
[100%] Built target A
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /home/imk/develop/so/cmake_prob/build/deps/A/lib/libA.so
-- Set runtime path of "/home/imk/develop/so/cmake_prob/build/deps/A/lib/libA.so" to "/home/imk/develop/so/cmake_prob/deps/A/build/deps/B/lib"
-- Installing: /home/imk/develop/so/cmake_prob/build/deps/A/./include
-- Installing: /home/imk/develop/so/cmake_prob/build/deps/A/./include/A.h
[ 80%] Completed 'project_A'
[ 80%] Built target project_A
[ 90%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable test
[100%] Built target test

And here's the program performing:
$ ./build/test
hello: 7

How did that work?
Here are the dynamic dependency notes the static linker has written in test:
$ readelf --dynamic build/test | egrep '(NEEDED|RUNPATH)'
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libA.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/home/imk/develop/so/cmake_prob/build/deps/A/lib]
 

The program needs libA.so, plus the Standard C++ and Standard C libraries. Dependencies
can be looked for in the RUNPATH, which is the installation path of libA.so, in addition to the default linker
search directories.
Here are the dependency notes that were previously written in libA.so, which
the linker consulted in the linkage of test
$ readelf --dynamic build/deps/A/lib/libA.so | egrep '(NEEDED|RUNPATH)'
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libB.so]
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/home/imk/develop/so/cmake_prob/deps/A/build/deps/B/lib]
 

libA.so needs libB.so and dependencies can be looked for in the installation directory of libB.so.
That RUNPATH was put there in A/CmakeLists.txt by the addition:
set_target_properties(A PROPERTIES 
                        INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/deps/B/lib"
                        )

which has the effect of adding the linker option:
    -Wl,-rpath="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/deps/B/lib"
    

to the linkage of libA.so.
Without that RUNPATH, if test is linked only against libA, the linker will find
only the note:
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libB.so]
 

when it inspects libA.so and will not know where to find this library. The linkage
will fail like this:
[ 90%] Linking CXX executable test
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libB.so, needed by /home/imk/develop/so/cmake_prob/build/deps/A/lib/libA.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: /home/imk/develop/so/cmake_prob/build/deps/A/lib/libA.so: undefined reference to `B::get()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

We'd need to link test explicitly against libB.so and also explicitly tell the static linker where to look:
g++ -o test main.o -L<libA-install-dir> -lA -L<libB-install-dir> -lB

But if we put the right RUNPATH into libA.so in its own linkage, then the linkage of test will use it
to locate libB.so, and we succeed in linking test without mentioning libB, as you want.
And would that be good practice?
As usual, it depends on the use-case.

Private libraries

If libB was genuinely a private library,
exclusively providing back-office services to libA and maybe a small number of
related specialised libraries including libA, then hard-coding a non-default installation RUNPATH for libB
into the dynamic dependency notes of libA would be using this linker capability for
its intended purpose. It will expedite the load time of libA clients because the
dynamic linker will have the hard-coded runpath to libB. It would also be good
citizenship of the system, because it will not contribute
to polluting the default search directories with private libraries, which marginally
degrades the load times of everything.

What does a program "know"?

But your motivation for wanting linkage of libA to imply linkage of dependencies isn't
that discriminating.

So, that any executable that wants to use A doesn't need to know every dependency that A
might need.

The language is metaphorical, but speaking metaphorically it's reasonable to
say that the external things an executable "knows about" are the external symbols that
it refers to. By that reckoning, the C++ source code of the executable determines
what symbols it knows about and the header files that its programmer has access to determine
what symbols it could know about it.
In particular, the client program test knows about symbols from libA and does not know
about any from libB, regardless of how test is linked. And because you do not expose
any of libB's headers through those of libA, you have have made it impossible
for a libA client to know about any of libBs symbols via libAs headers.
With that, you can consider the job done of encapsulating libA's dependency on libB,
regardless of how a libA client is linked. The pros and cons of hard-coding a runpath
for libB in libA are separate.

Public libraries

If libB is some general purpose library on the system - let's call it a public library -
then the builders of libA clients will expect libA not to hard-code a runpath for its dependency
on libB and will expect the libA docs to say "requires libB". For all you know, a libA
client app might also want the services of libB directly, as per its header files, in which
case it's for the client app builder to decide whether to hard-code libB's runpath in the the
linkage of the app - almost certainly a No.
Public libraries are the ones that are meant to be located by the dynamic linker by default search,
not bound to a hard-coded location. The builder of a libA client, where libA depends on a public
library libB, expects to link both of them explicitly and let the dynamic linker
find libB wherever it is, not where the builder of libA might have thought it should be.
That is why public libraries never hard-code runpaths for own dependencies. Consequently,
if you decide build a libA that hard-codes a runpath for its public dependency libB,
that will very rarely be enough to make the linkage of libA alone imply all of its dependencies.
libB itself will almost always have dependencies which are also public,
maybe with a longest chain like:
    libA -> libB -> libC -> libD -> libstdc++ -> libc
    

So hard-coding libBs runpath in libA will just imply libB to the linker
and the rest of its dependency tree - inconsistently - will still need to be
explicitly linked, unless you plough on until libA has a runpath for each
of them. You can see that this ploughing on squanders libAs prospects of portability, and defeats the point of using an OS in which the public libraries a program requires
can just be found.
The normal way of dodging long library lists in linkages
Of course programs frequently have transitive public dependencies
that you can't divine from the header files included in their source code, or shouldn't have to . If linking libA requires you to link also libB and libC, there needs to be some
linkage-friendly way in which the builder of libA can make this information available
to builders of libA clients.
The the most commonly used way of doing this is
pkg-config, (manual).
Probably the next most popular is cmake-packages.
Both of these solutions allow the builder of libA to package a configuration file - A.pc for pkg-config,
AConfig.cmake for Cmake - in the installation of the libA development package, from which the downstream client's build
system can effortlessly extract the required options to compile with the libA headers and link with libA, including
all its dependencies. These are the methods by which client builds that use public libraries routinely avoid coding
lengthy dependency lists in their linkage options. It's not done by the upstream library builders making their library pull in dependencies from hard-coded places.


There's a CMake way to fake the linkage of a static library target,
should you ever knowingly want to do that. Read Linking Object Libraries via $<TARGET_OBJECTS>
,
where in the explanation you'll find it mentioned that:


Since a static library does not link, it does not consume the object files from object libraries

You'll recognise the technique as a way of telling CMake to behave as if bag A is bag A + bag B.
